# Mylyn like App for my Desktop

Tags: bug-tracking

so i am a big Fan of Mylyn. I like to manage all my Tickets/Tasks etc in Trac.

I am looking forward to get an app like Mylyn for my regular Desktop outside Eclipse.
Its not really programming related...but managing Tasks is one challenge we are facing every Day.

Any suggestions?

Edit:
At the moment i am starting my own solution for this. I post it here when its ready.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download the minimal Eclipse platform - [the platform runtime binary](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5-200906111540/index.php#PlatformRuntime) - , add the [Mylyn 3.2 update site](http://eclipse.org/mylyn/downloads/) and install Mylyn.

You can't get smaller than this.

Answer (score 7):

[Tasktop](http://www.eweek.com/c/a/Application-Development/Tasktop-Updates-Mylyn-Tasktop-Tools-for-Eclipse-Galileo-134393/) is exactly that:

Comment: well very nice product...but very expensive too. any other Ideas?

Answer (score 5):

As Robert points out, you can install Mylyn and the Trac Connector into an Eclipse runtime to get the basic functionality. Tasktop is needed if you'd like further desktop integration, e.g.,

- Task-focused web browsing with IE (Embedded) or Firefox (External)
- GMail and Outlook/Exchange email integration (Create tasks from messages)
- Google and Outlook/Exchange calendar integration (View upcoming appointments)
- Linking local documents (View documents in your task contexts)
- Time tracking (Automatically generate reports)

Tasktop also provides access to additional [connectors](http://tasktop.com/connectors) if you need them.

Although Tasktop Pro isn't free, I encourage you to consider the value of the time savings Tasktop makes possible. If your organization is interested in Tasktop for your team, I can provide more information about the benefits and ROI.

Wesley Coelho
[Tasktop Technologies](http://tasktop.com)